# Flutter Screen from routes is loading before Localization

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization, in-app

I'm adding flutter to an existing app.

I localized my app, as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), and as I will display any flutter screen from legacy code, I decided to use named routes, as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes), but after using it, I realized that localization was loaded after I tried to render screen, so the _localizedValues was null.

When using hot reload (so localization was already loaded), it would display correctly, but when using hot restart, it gives the error because localizations was not loaded yet.

Any solution for this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NVM, it seems the way I was doing was not working, but I discovered another way that works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FlutterMainActivity.class).putExtra("route", "/your-route");
startActivity(intent);
```